# understanding scanf syntax

Tags: c, scanf

I have the following scanf code I am unable to understand::

```
char board[3][3];
int i;
for(i=0;i<3;i++) 
scanf("%s[^\n]%*c", board[i]);
```

Please help me understand word by word what the letters in scanf syntax mean.
Thankyou.

Comment: This appears to be trying to use a non-standard syntax to skip everything after the first word on each line.  What platform is this for?

Comment: @VaughnCato Any. This is standard. "I don't see it" != "It doesn't exist"...

Answer (score 3):

Read a sequence of non-whitespace characters, then `"[^"`, newline, `"]"`, then one more character which is not stored anywhere. I don't think this is what actually needed. You can read scanf manpage (google it) for correct syntax.

Explanation:

`%s` - capture a sequence of non-whitespace characters

`%[` - capture a sequence of characters determined by set (ending with ']')

That's why `%s[^\n]` seems wrong to me. Should be `%[^\n]` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Afaik,

What this does is, for 3 times (inside for loop), reads a line (with %s) till it encounters a newline char (with [^\n]) and discards the last (newline) char (with %*c).

```
%*c
```

Here, "*" will tell scanf to not store the value caught by "c". i.e. the newline char.