# Why does the return not work in my program? C

Tags: c, function

So I am a beginner in C and I was trying to use functions in my programs but I cant figure out why my function isn't returning 1 or 0, and if I put a printf("Hello"); in the middle of the loop in the function it isn't appearing in the console. Any help would be appreciated!

```
int Primo(int x);

int main() {
    Ex4_MED_4();
}

 void Ex4_MED_4(){
    int prime,number;
    printf("Pick a number:");
    scanf("%d",number);
    prime=Primo(number);
    printf("%d",prime);
}

int Primo(int x){
    for(int i=2;i<=x/2;i++){
        if (x%i==0) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%d",number)` - > `scanf("%d",&number)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [understanding scanf syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14027701/understanding-scanf-syntax)

Comment: You ignore the return value of `scanf()` at your own risk.

Comment: Save time, enable all warnings as expected with `scanf("%d",number);`

Comment: BTW, `Primo(x)` reports incorrect results when `x < 2`.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know  how to mark a comment has a solution, but thanks to @Eugene Sh. I was able to see I am brain dead and forgot to put a `&` in the `scanf()`. So `scanf("%d",number) --> scanf("%d",&number)`. If someone could tell me how to make him the top answer would appreciate!

Comment: do not use answers as comments

Comment: You can only accept an answer, not a comment. You might benefit by reading the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @P__J__ - Conversely, a lot of people leave the answers as comments instead of posting actual answer responses.  While helpful for solving an immediate problem, it also leaves the OP with no official answer to mark as the solution.